# How to get bottom position of current viewport on browser

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get the bottom position of the visible part of the document, not the height of document.

For example, my screen height is `768px` then the height of visible part is about `650px`, if the scroll height is `200px` then the bottom position will be around `850px`. I tried using `$(window).height()` but it returns the height of the document.

Comment: Thank Rory, it work when i create a new demo file, one script return different value on two page, maybe something wrong in my html code, omg i spent all day just for searching this

Answer (score 20):

Without jQuery

```
window.scrollY + window.innerHeight
```

Answer (score 8):

To achieve this you just need to add the `scrollTop()` of the `window` to its `height()` within the `scroll()` event handler, like this:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.foo').text($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height());
}).scroll();
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  height: 30000px;
}

.foo {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="foo"></div>
```

Comment: @compliance which version of jQuery are you using?